# Wordpress & ElasticSearch - or any enterprise search

Tags: search, wordpress

Let me be a bit boring and tell you what I've been struggling to do ;)

90K posts - each post is an app from iTunes or Android Play. Each post has custom fields - pricing, free, release date, etc… - and the Wordpress default search just can't handle it fast enough.

I'm trying to put a search in place that will allow the end user to do a "normal" keyword search but I'd like them to also be able to select or, at the least, have in the results, the ability to filter via category, tag, and some custom fields.

Ideally I'd like to be able to configure this so that I can do something like - have results display vertically, have facets display to the side of the results allowing the user to say "Oh, I just want to see apps that were released in the last year…" - or whatever.

Having tried Solr, and WPSolr (wouldn't display facets), OpenSemantic Search -doesn't work at all, Solr with LucidWorks Fusion (to confusing for me - I'm not a developer), and now using ElasticSearch having pretty much have tried everything else.

ElasticPress Plugin works great - it indexes VERY fast - and so far it's as close to a solution as I've found.

But it seem to just bypass WP-Query yet still displays results as if it were WP's search - no facets, no filters, etc..I've tried installing another WP seach plugin - search and filter for instance - thinking it would just hitch a ride on the ElasticPress WP-Query - but no joy. Any other plugin for WP searching seemed to just bypass EP.

I have plenty of infrastructure, servers, etc…and WP and EP and ES are all running on an Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty, MariaDB 10.x, PHP5.9? (the latest) with a plenty of ram&disk…and this is the last piece of my puzzle…of course it's the piece I can't find!

Is there any hope? :)

Thanks for your time!
Rob

Comment: I did read the tag - this isn't about installing or maintaining Wordpress. It's about using ElasticSearch Server in a PHP environment which happens to be Wordpress. There's no problem with Wordpress. And Webmasters specifically prohibits questions about servers, html, JS, & CMS. Superuse is for questions about "Computer Software". This is definitely a software question.

Answer (score 0):

A wordpress plugin that i have experienced recently is https://fulltextsearch.org/. This plugin creates a word-based index to smooth the search as this plugin is written in PHP and doesn't require an installation of any additional software. I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), which applies to suggesting plugins for Wordpress too. Pay particular attention to the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!